# ValueError: WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope on converting Flask Wsgi Application to Asgi Application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wsgi, asgi

I am developing a web server using flask 2.0.2 and deploying using hypercorn. I want to deploy it as asgi application.

My main.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from asgiref.wsgi import WsgiToAsgi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
async def hello_word():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "<p> Hello World </p>"

asgi_app = WsgiToAsgi(app)
```

When deploying the server:  `hypercorn main:asgi_app`
The following error is raised but the server is deployed successfully.

```
[2021-11-29 20:15:30 +0530] [41394] [ERROR] ASGI Framework Lifespan error, continuing without Lifespan support
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/lifespan.py", line 32, in handle_lifespan
    await invoke_asgi(self.app, scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
  File "/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hypercorn/utils.py", line 246, in invoke_asgi
    await app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/wsgi.py", line 21, in __call__
    await WsgiToAsgiInstance(self.wsgi_application)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/wsgi.py", line 36, in __call__
    raise ValueError("WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope")
ValueError: WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope
[2021-11-29 20:15:30 +0530] [41394] [INFO] Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (CTRL + C to quit)
```

I am able to hit the route defined but the cause of this error is still unknown to me. On looking into the stack trace, i found that when deploying the handle_lifespan function in hypercorn/asyncio/lifespan.py is called which looks like this:

```
    async def handle_lifespan(self) -> None:
        self._started.set()
        scope: LifespanScope = {"type": "lifespan", "asgi": {"spec_version": "2.0"}}
        try:
            await invoke_asgi(self.app, scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
        except LifespanFailureError:
            # Lifespan failures should crash the server
            raise
        except Exception:
            self.supported = False
            if not self.startup.is_set():
                message = "ASGI Framework Lifespan error, continuing without Lifespan support"
            elif not self.shutdown.is_set():
                message = "ASGI Framework Lifespan error, shutdown without Lifespan support"
            else:
                message = "ASGI Framework Lifespan errored after shutdown."

            await self.config.log.exception(message)
        finally:
            self.startup.set()
            self.shutdown.set()
```

This defines the scope type as "lifespan" and passes this scope to the WsgiToAsgiInstance class that checks the scope of the request:

```
if scope["type"] != "http":
    raise ValueError("WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope")
```

Can someone help me understanding it better?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be ignored (and with the next release of Hypercorn it will report as a warning instead). It indicates what you already know - WSGI apps don't support the lifespan protocol.