raise ValueError("WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope") ValueError: WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope
I am Getting this error when deploy my Flask app to aws lambda
Here is my code
@app.route('/dmca', methods=['GET'])
def get_dmca():

    url = request.args.get('url')
    if not url:
        return jsonify({'error': 'URL parameter is missing'}), 400
    
    result = process_url(url=url)
    
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
        'result': result
    }

    return jsonify(response)

asgi_app = WsgiToAsgi(app)

handler = Mangum(asgi_app, lifespan="off")

I am trying to add lifespan="off"

There is no point using ASGI on a Lambda as it will only ever handle one request at a time, so you can just using the WSGI app as-is without converting with WsgiToAsgi. The error appears to be something to do with WSGI apps not understanding the lifespan attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157065/valueerror-wsgi-wrapper-received-a-non-http-scope-on-converting-flask-wsgi-appl
